# cakephp Cell class *is missing

Tags: php, cakephp

Cell class headerCell is missing. 
Cake\View\Exception\MissingCellException

\src\template\layout\home.ctp (default homepage index)

```
<body>
<?php echo $this->cell('header'); ?>

<?php echo $this->cell('logobar'); ?>

<?php echo $this->element('mainnav'); ?>

--------------------
\view\cell\headerCell.php
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\View\Cell;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class HeaderCell extends Cell
{
    public function display()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The file name should be `HeaderCell.php` not `headerCell.php`

In fact your directory names casing is also incorrect, they should be all CamelCased, so `src/View/Cell/HeaderCell.php`.